# Can we use the expression "1 shot kills 2 birds" to express the idea that you do 1 thing but it can have many benefits?

Tags: expressions

Ok, sometime in life you do 1 thing but that action can give 2 or more benefits.

For example, before owning a car you have to wake up early everyday and have a 10 minutes walking to the station to wait for the train. Now, you've bought a car and you said.

> Buying this car is like "1 shot kills 2 birds" because I don't need to
>   wake up early and I don't need to spend 10 minutes walking to the
>   station and don't need to wait for the train.

so, Can we use the expression "1 shot kills 2 birds" to express the idea that you do 1 thing but it can have many benefits?

If it has 2 benefits then I'll say "1 shot kills 2 birds" but

If it has 3 or more benefits then do I have to say "1 shot kills 3 or many birds" or just "1 shot kills 2 birds"?

also, Is there any other similar expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The commonly-used idiom is to ***["kill two birds with one stone"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/kill-two-birds-with-one-stone)***.

> to succeed in achieving two things in a single action: I killed two birds with one stone and picked the kids up on the way to the train station.

Comment: what if it can solve 3 or more problems? do u say "kill 3 or many birds with 1 stone"?

Comment: Whilst it's less common, I'm sure everyone would understand what you meant if you said "I was visiting London so I met with Dave who lives there and picked up a book for my friend, killing three birds with one stone".

Comment: Another dictionary gives:  Fig. to solve two problems at one time with a single action.  http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/kill+two+birds+with+one+stone

Solving two problems with one action isn't exactly equivalent to bringing two benefits with one action. I think the former is closer to the common usage of the idiom.

Comment: Let's say achieving two objectives.  Birds aren't necessarily _problems_ or _benefits_. Maybe they're a _project_; something you throw stones (projectiles) at.